# Display comments only for users with "administer comments" permission

Tags: comments

In `hook_node_view_alter`, I'm trying to restrict the display of comments to users who have the "administer comments" permission.

So far I have this but it is not working.

```
if (isset($build['comment'])) {
  if (!\Drupal::currentUser()->hasPermission('administer comments')) {
    $build['comment']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution below:

```
$build['comment']['#access'] = Drupal::currentUser()->hasPermission('administer comments');
```